# Использование React Native и для мобильных приложений, и для веба

Tags: react-native

Есть ли преимущества в том, чтобы на React Native писать и web-приложение, и мобильные приложения под iOS/Android? Или будет проще на RN реализовать только мобильные приложения, а для веб использовать более привычные для себя технологии?

Я недавно во фронтенде, опыта не очень много, освоение RN по документации идет не очень просто и постоянно сталкиваюсь с тем, что то, что работает на мобиле, не работает в браузере и наоборот. Кажется, будто было бы проще RN оставить только для мобилок. У меня просто пока не хватает знаний и опыта, чтобы оценить плюсы использования RN для разных типов устройств или это действительно не лучшее решение?
Спасибо!

Comment: RN для мобильных приложений. Просто React для веб приложений. Они кстати не одинаковые. 
Принципы для веб и мобильных различаются. Должна быть конкретная цель

Comment: Мобильные разработчики не часто выбирают RN для мультиплатформенности. Многие выбирают Котлин и Котлин Мультиплатформ

Comment: @sterx Я как раз обратила внимание, что принципы веб и мобильных приложений отличаются и не понимаю, почему руководство решило реализовывать и веб, и мобилки с помощью RN, отсюда и вопрос. Спасибо!